# Add more columns to the Highlight content web part

Tags: sharepoint-online

Good evening, is it possible to add more columns to the list layout of the web part? I want to show a site column that is being used on all sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is NO.

We can’t customize the OOB modern web part, If it's critical to have this behavior, then a developer can [create a custom web part via SPFx](https://github.com/spplante/react-content-query).